# What finite difference method do I use for below data?

Tags: finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

The data in the table below represents the altitude $H$ (in feet) of a small rocket that is launched vertically upward as a function of time $t$ (in seconds):
$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
t\text{ (s)}&0&2&4&6&8&10&12&14\\
H\text{ (ft)}&0&80&350&800&1400&2100&3100&4100\\
\hline
t\text{ (s)}&16&18&20&22&24&26&28&30\\
H\text{ (ft)}&5300&6500&7900&9300&10700&12200&13800&15300
\end{array}$$

- Develop a computer program to obtain the rocket's velocity $v$ and acceleration $a$ at each point using the finite-difference formulae with a truncation error of $O(h^2)$.
- Then, display the results in three plots (*altitude* vs. time, *velocity* vs. time and *acceleration* vs. time).
- Comment on the results you show in the plots!

---

I have to develop a program to obtain the rocket's velocity and acceleration at the same time instant, using finite difference formula of $O(h^2)$ truncation error.

Which type of finite difference method do I use (forward / backward / central) and (two / three / four point)? Moreover, what is the significance of truncation error in this context?

Comment: Only one of forward, backward, and central difference methods has error of $O(h^2)$ the other two have error of $O(h)$.

Comment: And basically only one of them is a three point method

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan so can we rule out 4 point method? I forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: @user1 Not true! Forward & Backward are of order 1 and thus have truncation error of order 2!

Comment: So you forward and backward suffice here.